# use of if (.) {} else {} within lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I have a data frame of mostly numeric columns, each with few unique elements. Those with 20 or fewer unique values, I'd like to convert to factors as is, those with more, I'd like to convert to factors using `gtools::quantcut`.

What am I not understanding about the behavior of `ifelse` within `lapply`?

```
d <- data.frame(a = sample(1:10, 100, replace=T), 
                                b = sample(1:10, 100 ,replace=T), 
                                c = sample(1:30, 100 ,replace=T),
                                d = sample(1:30, 100 ,replace=T),
                                e = sample(1:30, 100 ,replace=T))

wrong <- as.data.frame(lapply(d[,sapply(d, is.numeric)],
function(x) ifelse(length(unique(x)) <=20, 
                   as.factor(x),
                   quantcut(x))))
dim(wrong)
# [1]  1 5
right <- as.data.frame(lapply(d[, sapply(d, is.numeric)],
                       function(x) { 
                           if(length(unique(x)) <= 20) {
                           return(as.factor(x))
                           }
                           quantcut(x)
                           }))
dim(right)
# [1] 100    5
```

Comment: Seemed pretty clear that you should not be using `ifelse` which is a different R function and requires all the involved vectors to be the same length which `unique` pretty effectively screws up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are asking `ifelse` to return a vector when the test argument is a scalar. The ifelse statement in the `wrong` way you have above is returning the first element of the desired vector. From the help file: `ifelse` can only return "a value that is the same shape as `test`".

Comment: Gah. I thought I understood `ifelse` so well I didn't even go to the help file. Thanks for getting it so quickly.